# JS singleton class object

Tags: javascript, singleton

I'd like to use a custom instance as a singleton.

```
class MyInstance {
  static instance = new MyInstance();

  static getInstance() {
      if(MyInstance.instance === null) MyInstance.instance = new MyInstance();
      return this.instance;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

The above code works as a singleton but I'd like to use it like this.

```js
const ins1 = MyInstance.getInstance(1); 
const ins2 = MyInstance.getInstance(2);
const _ins1 = MyInstance.getInstance(1); // it has same object to ins1 as singleton.
const __ins1 = MyInstance.getInstance(1);

// ins1, _ins1 and __ins1 are same.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, this is not a Singleton anymore, but rather a Factory/Registry, for which you can use a static `Map` to keep track of objects.

```js
class Box {
    static map = new Map();

    static get(key) {
        if (!this.map.has(key))
            this.map.set(key, new this(key))
        return this.map.get(key)
    }

    constructor(key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    hello() {
        console.log('hey', this.key)
    }
}

arr = [
    Box.get(1),
    Box.get(2),
    Box.get(1),
]

arr.forEach(b => b.hello())
console.log(arr[0] === arr[1])
console.log(arr[0] === arr[2])
```

Also, it's a matter of preference, but I'd use separate classes for instances and for the Factory itself (e.g. `Foo` and `FooFactory`).